# $f(m + f(n)) = f(f(m)) + f(n)$

Tags: functional-equations

I found this one in the list of [IMO'96](http://olympiads.win.tue.nl/imo/imo96/imo96.txt) (3) problems and decided to have a go at it, but could not complete the solution. So $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers and $f$ takes values in the same set:

$$f(m + f(n)) = f(f(m)) + f(n)$$

Let $m=n=0$:
$$f(f(0))=f(f(0))+f(0)$$
hence
$$f(0)=0$$
Now let $m=0$:
$$f(f(n))=f(n)$$
therefore:
$$f(m+f(n))=f(m)+f(n)$$
Now consider the following possibilities

1) $f(m)=f(n) \implies m=n$
$$f(m+f(n))=f(m)+f(n)$$
$$f(n+f(m))=f(n)+f(m)$$
By symmetry of the RHS:
$$f(m+f(n))=f(n+f(m))$$
Hence, by assumption
$$m+f(n)=n+f(m)$$
$$f(n)-n=f(m)-m$$
Since the two sides are independent they must be both equal to a constant
$$f(n)-n=C$$
$$f(0)=0 \implies C=0 \implies f(n)=n$$
2) It is the second part where I got confused. I assumed $f(m)=f(n)$ where $m \ne n$, so that
$$f(m+f(n))=2f(n)$$
then figure that since RHS does not depend on $m$ whereas LHS does, then $f=C$ and deduced from the original equation that $C$ must be 0. But then I relayed that in fact here I have some particular values of $m$ and $n$ and not just something arbitrary. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: The RHS _does_ depend on $m$, in a sense. In this argument at this point, you are not free to let $n$ take on any value; $n$ can only take on values that are in the pre-image of $f(m)$. So you can't conclude that $f$ is constant, but rather that $f$ is constant on subsets of $\mathbb{N}_0$ where the output of $f$ is fixed - a tautology.

Comment: $f = 0$ and $f(n) = n$ are not the only solutions. Take for example $f(2n) = f(2n+1) = 2n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is a solution to $f(m+f(n)) = f(f(n)) + f(m)$ then either $f \equiv 0$ or there is some $k\in\mathbb N$ and some $a_0,\ldots,a_{k-1} \in \mathbb N_0$ with $a_0 = 0$ s.t. $f(kn+r) = k(n+a_r)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N_0, 0 \leq r < k$.

It is easy to verify that these functions are indeed solutions of the functional equation. To prove that every solution is of this kind, we first make some observations about fixed points.

**Claim:** Let $f$ be a solution and denote by $F$ the set of fixed points of $f$, i.e. $F = \{ n\in \mathbb N_0 : f(n) = n \}$. Then the following statements hold:

1. $0 \in F$
2. $F$ is closed under addition, i.e. if $x,y\in F$, then also $x+y \in F$.
3. If $x \in F$ and $x+y \in F$ , then also $y \in F$.
4. $F = k\mathbb N_0$ for some $k \in \mathbb N_0$.

**Proof:**
(1) follows from $f(0) = 0$. If $x,y\in F$ then from $f(x+f(y)) = f(x)+f(y)$ we get $f(x+y) = x+y$, hence $x+y \in F$. If $x,x+y\in F$ then 
$$y+x = f(y+x) = f(y+f(x)) = f(y)+f(x) = f(y) + x,$$
hence $f(y) = y$. (4) now follows from the previous statements: If $0$ is the only fixed point then $F = \{0\} = 0\mathbb N_0$ and we are finished. Otherwise, there is a smallest non-zero fixed point $k$. By (2), $k\mathbb N_0 \subseteq F$. If $x$ is any other fixed point then write $x = kn+r$ with $n\in \mathbb N_0$ and $0 \leq r < k$. By (3), we have $r \in F$. But $k$ is the smallest non-zero fixed point and $r < k$, so $r = 0$ and $x = kn \in k\mathbb N_0$.
(This was basically the proof that $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain.)

Now observe that $f(\mathbb N_0) \subseteq F$, since $f(f(n)) = f(n)$ for all $n$. Therefore, if $F = \{0\}$ then $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$, i.e. $f$ is constantly zero.
Otherwise, $F = k\mathbb N_0$ for some non-zero $k$. Now let $a_r' := f(r)$ for $0 \leq r < k$. Then $a_0' = 0$, and for all $n \in \mathbb N_0$ and $0\leq r < k$ we have
$$f(kn+r) = f(r + f(kn)) = f(r) + f(kn) = f(r) + kn = kn + a_r'.$$
Furthermore, $kn+a_r' \in f(\mathbb N_0) \subseteq k\mathbb N_0$, hence $k|a_r'$. Write $a_r' = k a_r$, then $f(kn+r) = k(n+a_r)$, as claimed.

Comment: I can't help thinking there are some redundant steps in (1), but many thanks indeed. I guess this is the level of detail expected at the IMO level

Comment: Can we just say that $f(0)=0$, and that $g:=f-\operatorname{id}$ is periodic?

Comment: @alex.jordan: $g = f-\operatorname{id}$ is periodic, but in addition $g(m) \equiv -m \pmod k$. Also, for $f$ to have values in $\mathbb N_0$, you need further restrictions on $g$.